# Subquery naming conventions

Tags: sql-server, subquery, alias

I am using the following statement to return values from the table.But here i am getting error as `The multi-part identifier "a.NoOfLocks" could not be bound.`

The sql statement is given below

```
select count(cu.CashsafeUserId) as NoOfUsers ,a.NoOfLocks as 'NoOfLocks',
     (select count(CashSafeLockId) as NoOfLocks 
      from CashSafeLocks cl inner join Cashsafes c 
        on c.CashsafeId=cl.CashSafeId 
      where c.cashsafeid=22 ) as  a 
from CashsafeUsers cu inner join Cashsafes c 
  on c.CashsafeId=cu.CashSafeId 
where c.CashsafeId=22
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I had put `','` in my sqlquery and now exception message is different.I've updated the question pls look into it

Answer (score 2):

You can use sub query to calculate the `NoOfLocks` value for the same id
 
Try this:

```
select count(cu.CashsafeUserId) as NoOfUsers , 
     (select count(CashSafeLockId)
      from CashSafeLocks cl inner join Cashsafes c 
        on c.CashsafeId=cl.CashSafeId 
      where c.cashsafeid=22 ) as NoOfLocks
from CashsafeUsers cu inner join Cashsafes c 
  on c.CashsafeId=cu.CashSafeId 
where c.CashsafeId=22
```

Alternatively you can use derived table, solution should be something along these lines:

```
select count(cu.CashsafeUserId) as NoOfUsers , a.NoOfLocks 
from CashsafeUsers cu inner join Cashsafes c 
  on c.CashsafeId=cu.CashSafeId  
  left outer join 
     (select count(CashSafeLockId)as NoOfLocks, cc.CashsafeId    as CashsafeId
      from CashSafeLocks cl inner join Cashsafes cc 
        on cc.CashsafeId=cl.CashSafeId 
       Group BY cc.CashsafeId   
      ) as a on c.CashsafeId= a.CashsafeId
where c.CashsafeId=22
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but what am i doing wrong in the above statement

Comment: It seems to me that you're trying to create a derived table in the `SELECT` part of the statement.. you can use a sub query instead that will give the the result immediately `(select count....) as NoOfLocks`

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(cu.CashsafeUserId) as NoOfUsers,count(CashSafeLockId) as NoOfLocks
from CashsafeUsers cu 
inner join Cashsafes c on c.CashsafeId=cu.CashSafeId 
full outer join CashSafeLocks cl on c.CashsafeId=cl.CashSafeId and cu.CashsafeId=cl.CashSafeId 
where cu.CashsafeId=22
```